# Исключение @Controller не работает

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

У меня есть два артефакта, которые включены в основной проект. Первый содержит пакет `com.parent.controller`. Второй - `com.child.controller`. Каждый пакет содержит один контоллер - `ParentController` и `ChildContoller`, соответственно. Оба они имеют одинаковый `RequestMapping` (например, просто `/abc`). Также я включил фильтр для исключения `ParentController`. Но в любом случае у меня ловится исключение:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping`. Как это можно исправить?

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.parent", "com.child"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.parent", "com.child"}, excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.parent\\..*Controller"),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = ParentController.class)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут два варианта

Вам нужно создать отдельный маппинг для ParentController и Childcontroller

```
@Controller("/parent")
public class ParentController

@Controller("/child")
public class ChildController
```

И потом уже, исходя из общего маппинга в контроллере, присваивать свой "/abc"

Если это не помогло, то поменяйте свой

```
@RequestMapping(name="/abc")
```

на

```
@RequestMapping(value="/abc")
```

Comment: Я не могу менять ParentController. Мне нужно через ChildController "переопределить" маппинг на него.